# ASP.NET Core MVC + Vue + Single File Components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, sass

I'm looking at integrating a decent client side library into a new project and have come across Vue.
I currently develop in Visual Studio 2019, with ASP.NET Core MVC and am looking to include Vue into the mix.

I'm struggling to find any article that fits what I want to do, so am reaching out to get some insight on how to -

- Include `Vue.js` into the project (happy to use `NPM`)
- Create a `single file component` in the project
- Ideally in the component, if I could use `sass` and `typescript`

I'm a bit foggy on the details, not strong with `NPM` or `Webpack`, and hate bloating out a project with all these dependencies on dependences that NPM seems to be capable of.

What are the minimum requirements/packages to get this working?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The first of many [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+core+mvc+vue) for _"ASP.NET Core MVC vue"_ ~ https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/27/build-crud-app-vuejs-netcore

Comment: Phil, unfortunately this and many others only cover about a tenth of my question above, missing out fundamental parts along the way while choosing to ignore the tools visual studio provide. The article linked in comment is also prior to .net core 3 - am looking for a more current explanation that hopefully goes into detail not only what NPM packages to use, but why.